# Вопрос об асинхронном методе

Tags: java, concurrency

Есть вопрос по поводу асинхронной реализации метода, в каких случаях она выгодна? сейчас метод выполняется быстрее чем его реализация, а если синхронизировать с помощью семафор не вижу сильных отличий от одного потока

```
Call call = client.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Асинхронные вызовы не блокируют выполнение потока, поток может выполнять полезную работу во время ожидания ответа на запрос.

Comment: `метод выполняется быстрее чем его реализация` - это что имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Komdosh то есть если у меня многопоточная программа и методы отмечены как synchronized, то без обратных вызовов поток будет блокироваться?

Comment: @RomanKonoval допустим метод возвращает переменную, а реализации onResponse инициализирует переменную, тогда программа выдаст налл и после переменная будет инициализирована

Comment: @ArtemiiKurilko ну да, более того если вы используете `synchronized` то все потоки встанут в этом месте и будут ожидать ответ на один запрос

Comment: @Komdosh как сделать чтобы методы выполнялись паралельно? убрать synchronized и добавить реализацию Callback?

Comment: В вопросе и обменом реплик в комментариях много возможностей истолковать вопросы и ответы неправильно и сделать абсолютно неправильные выводы. Нужны не абстрактные вопросы типа `если у меня многопоточная программа и методы отмечены как synchronized, то без обратных вызовов поток будет блокироваться`, а точный код. Т.к. ответ на этот вопрос зависит от того какие методы помечены и на каких объектах они вызываются и еще много нюансов. И в зависимости от этого ответ `да` может быть как верным, так и нет. В общем случае правильный ответ - `это зависит от деталей не включенных в вопрос`

Comment: @ArtemiiKurilko Асинхронность != Многопоточность, Роман дал исчерпывающий комментарий на ваши вопросы, действительно, чтобы что-то советовать не хватает деталей.